# How to return distinct result in linq to collection

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Below query result duplicates of class code.

```
cboFilterValues.DataSource = (From i In allDetails Select New LookUpItem With {.ItemText = i.ClassCode, .ItemValue = i.ClassCode} Distinct).ToList()
```

Can any one suggest me how i could achieve distinct result for above query. I need result set as IList(Of LookupItems)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Distinct` is not working because (presumably - you didn't provide the code) you have not overridden the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your `LookUpItem` class, so instances are being compared using reference equality.  If you implement those methods, the Distinct should work:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(o As Object) As Boolean
    If o Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.GetType().Equals(o.GetType()) Then Return False
    Dim other = DirectCast(o, LookUpItem)
    Return Me.ItemText = other.ItemText ' or some other fields
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Return Me.ItemText.GetHashCode() ' or some other fields
End Function
```

Alternatively, you could modify your query a little, since you are only using the `ClassCode` property from `allDetails`, and put the distinct there (assuming that `ClassCode` is a `String`, or something else that uses value equality):

```
cboFilterValues.DataSource = (
    From i In (From d In allDetails Select d.ClassCode Distinct)
    Select New LookUpItem With {.ItemText = i, .ItemValue = i}
).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cboFilterValues.DataSource = (From x In (From i In allDetails Select i Distinct) Select New LookUpItem With {.ItemText = x.ClassCode, .ItemValue = x.ClassCode}).Tolist
```

I assuming what you have above doesn't work because of some problem with the select new, this should get round it if that's the problem.
Tim